# Increasing time of session.run() execution in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem with Tensorflow. I retrain inception model according to this tutorial [https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining][1] and i want to live classify images from camera. The problem is with changing image to tensor. I modyfi a function from this tutorial to load images not from file but directly from camera. With every iteration of my code method session.run() takes longer and longer and i don't know why. Here is my code:

```
def read_tensor_from_camera(image,
                        input_height=299,
                        input_width=299,
                        input_mean=0,
                        input_std=255):

    float_caster = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0)
    resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
    normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])

    start = time.time()
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    result = sess.run(normalized)
    stop = time.time()
    print(stop - start)

    return result


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image = cv2.resize(frame, (input_height, input_width))
    t = read_tensor_from_camera(image)
    cv2.imshow('frame', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> 0.024958372116088867
>   0.021515846252441406
>   0.024405956268310547
>   0.024140119552612305
>   0.02186441421508789
>   0.023257970809936523
>   0.02323007583618164
>   0.024866819381713867
>   0.030565977096557617
>   0.025953292846679688
>   0.025441408157348633
>   0.026473522186279297
>   0.023244380950927734
>   0.025677204132080078
>   0.024083375930786133
>   0.024756908416748047
>   0.024300098419189453
>   0.023919343948364258
>   0.026715993881225586
>   0.02456498146057129
>   0.027322769165039062
>   0.02640247344970703
>   0.02555561065673828
>   0.0270078182220459
>   0.0286102294921875
>   0.02633523941040039
>   0.02658367156982422
>   0.02969074249267578
>   0.026103973388671875
>   0.02613973617553711
>   0.02724480628967285
>   0.026676654815673828
>   0.02712845802307129
>   0.02947235107421875
>   0.030956745147705078
>   0.03170061111450195
>   0.027563095092773438
>   0.03021693229675293
>   0.028293848037719727
>   0.03078293800354004
>   0.02852654457092285
>   0.03080129623413086
>   0.032123565673828125
>   0.03287243843078613

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, i write my own function to create normalized tensor from cv image:

```
def convert_tensor_from_camera(image)
    image = image / 255
    return [image]
```

image is resized by openCV an I must only normalize image by divide it by max value of pixel (255) and it works :)